# Pagination not showing number in Laravel 8

Tags: pagination, laravel-8

I am trying to do use pagination, and it works fine. However, in the pagination, I only see the following.

> « Previous Next » 
> Showing 1 to 10 of 44 results

How can I make the pagination with Laravel so that I can see pagination numbers?

> < 1 2 3 4 5 ... etc >

I have 44 rows in my database

**Controller**

```php
public function daftar()
{
    $TMhs = DB::table('mahasiswa')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(10);

    return view('Mahasiswa', ['mhs' => $TMhs]);
}
```

**Blade/View**

```php
@foreach($mhs as $i => $DMhs)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $i+1+($mhs->perPage()*($mhs->currentPage()-1)) }}</td>
        <td>{{$DMhs->nama}}</td>
        <td>{{$DMhs->umur}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">{{$DMhs->desa}}</td>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid lightblue;">
            <a href="/kontrol/getedit/{{$DMhs->id}}" class="pranala">Edit</a>
            |
            <a href="/kontrol/hapus/{{$DMhs->id}}" class="pranala">Hapus</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>
    <div class="tgLuar">
        <div class="tgDalam" style="width: 35%; text-align: left">
            Halaman: {{ $mhs->currentPage() }}<br>
            Jumlah Data : {{ $mhs->total() }}<br>
            Data per Halaman : {{ $mhs->perPage() }}<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tgLuar">
        <div class="tgDalam">
            {{ $mhs->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so i just found video about someone showing pagination in laravel 8. [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mBbMQb1Kew&list=PLz_YkiqIHesvWMGfavV8JFDQRJycfHUvD&index=21)

He is having the same thing here.

Comment: i had the same issue, however i was using tailwindcss. pay attention to your .hidden classes inside pagination .blade templates. might be working, but CSS rules wont show it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i customize it my self. I change
`{{ $mhs->links() }}`
to

```php
<div class="tgLuar">
        <div class="tgDalam">
          @if($mhs->currentPage() != 1)
            <a href="{{ $mhs->url(1) }}">«&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="{{ $mhs->previousPageUrl() }}"><&nbsp;</a>
              @for($i=1; $i<=$mhs->lastPage(); $i++) 
                @if($i== $mhs->currentPage()) {
                    <a class="pranala" ><b>{{ $i }}</b>&nbsp;</a>
                 @else
                    <a href="{{ $mhs->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}&nbsp;</a>
                 @endif
              @endfor
              @if($mhs->currentPage() != $mhs->lastPage())
            <a href="{{ $mhs->nextPageUrl() }}">>&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="{{ $mhs->url($mhs->lastPage()) }}">»</a>
               @endif
        </div>
```

i hope it will answer someone else who have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

You may call the paginator's useBootstrap method within the boot method of your App\Providers\AppServiceProvider class:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap

Comment: didn't worked for me

Comment: @NomanJaved please read out the official doc and check your laravel version is it version8?

Comment: it's not working for a custom query, didn't get why. for simple queries like selecting using a model name is working.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10x

> If you are using Laravel's default Tailwind pagination views and the Tailwind JIT engine, you should ensure your application's tailwind.config.js file's content key references Laravel's pagination views so that their Tailwind classes are not purged:

```
content: [
'./resources/**/*.blade.php',
'./resources/**/*.js',
'./resources/**/*.vue',
'./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
```

],